# Split strings with TStrings, omitting CRLF delimiter

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I have string `'AAA'+#$0d+#$0a+'BBB'+#$01d+'CCC'`. I need to split according #$1d character like:

```
'AAA'+#$0d+#$0a+'BBB'
'CCC'
```

I'm using function:

```
procedure Split(Delimiter: Char; Str: string; ListOfStrings: TStrings) ;
begin
   ListOfStrings.Clear;
   ListOfStrings.Delimiter     := Delimiter;
   ListOfStrings.DelimitedText := Str;
   ListOfStrings.StrictDelimiter:= true;
end;
...
split(#$1d,'AAA'+#$0d+#$0a+'BBB'+#$01d+'CCC',sl);
```

Unfortunately it splits also according CRLF that I don't need.

How to have strings spited just by #$1d?

Answer (score 5):

You have to set `ListOfStrings.StrictDelimiter:= true;` before setting the of the property DelimitedText.

```
   ListOfStrings.StrictDelimiter:= true;
   ListOfStrings.DelimitedText := Str;
```

Comment: @KenWhite I don't own 2007, works as expected with D2009, XE, XE3